# c# organize multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, client, server

I'm trying to write a client and server program in C#, the client sends request to server the server handle the request in threads and send response to the client.

I write the client and server but the problem is, some threads uses too much memory and blocks the other requests.
Is there any way to limit a thread or the application memory usage.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot define memory limits for "per-thread" .The memory is allocated from shared pool.

Answer (score 1):

There is no any mechanisms to restrict memory usage on dedicated threads. It's obvious that there are some architectural and\or coding bugs in your program.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define memory limits for "per-thread" .The memory is allocated from shared pool.Instead one option would be able to make a queue,then have fixed number of threads(1,2,3,4 etc).

This way if request is made it'll handle them but 4 at a time(or however many you want).In this way you can prevent the memory.